# Everyone in my organization call see *all* of my Google Sheets (spreadsheet) documents. How do I prevent default access from within my organization?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-docs

A few minutes ago, I hopped on a co-workers computer who was working with Excel for inventory tracking, trying to get her to use Google Sheets instead. After logging her in, I was (very) surprised to see *all* of the files I have personally created in Google Sheets within my organization's Google account shared with my coworker. Some of these files are sensitive and are not intended to be shared with everyone.

So I'm looking for a "switch"/quick fix that allows me to prevent my Drive files from being shared within my organization by default.

I keep googling for answers for this and continue to run into explanations as to how to share files with people outside of my organization, which is quite easy and not what I'm trying to do. Thanks for your time

Comment: About to put a bounty on this..

Comment: Do you have superadmin access to your G Suite domain or are you a user?

Comment: Yes indeed I do